# Javascript or jQuery inputbox text field writing with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, textfield

I have to use a web application during my work, what I would like to fill with my created extension (I'm not programmer...).

The web app has two input fields, what I can't fill effectively, because, when I fill it with js commands below, the strings appear, but the "Add" button is not enabled. And, when I enable that, I'm not able to send the data to server the button click().

When I click with my mouse to the other side of the dom, the strings hide, and I realize, the values are in value attribute, but not in defaultValue. If I fill the fields with key pressing, naturally, the strinsg are not hidden if I click other side of the DOM.

I try to write data inputs using jQuery and simple js too:

input field 1:

```js
$('#autocomplete-sa-material').focus();
$('#autocomplete-sa-material').attr('value', 'A-10035951');
$('#autocomplete-sa-material').attr('placeholder', 'A-10035951');
```

OR

```js
arrr = document.getElementById('autocomplete-sa-material');
arrr.setAttribute("value", "A-10035951");
```

input field 2:

```js
$('#input-sa-quantity').focus();
$('#input-sa-quantity').val('27875');
brrr = document.getElementById('input-sa-quantity');
brrr.setAttribute("value", "27875");
```

I think, the problem is that the fields are modified by functions after change event. The first field can be fill using droplist, where you can select the exact material type. But, if you type keys, the droplist is filtered by the string, that you write (AJAX?). I can fill this inputbox simple Ctrl+C - Ctrl + V from an excel.

The second field, the quantity type is decimal with depicted in groups of thousands (using space character every 3 characters before). When I press the keys, the page exam the string, and create the groups from the string.

Could somebody help me, how I write the input textfield, to I could send data from there to the server?

I would like to help to change the two input text field with js or jQuery.

**Updated**:

I get some very good idea, there is only one problem, what I would like to solve:

I modified the recommended code minimally and it ran perfect and do what it have to do. The modified code was these:

```
arrr = document.getElementById('autocomplete-sa-material');
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
arrr.value = "A-10035951";
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
let event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
arrr.dispatchEvent(event);

brrr = document.getElementById('input-sa-quantity');
brrr.value = "27875";
let event2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
brrr.dispatchEvent(event2);
```

There is only one problem left:
I have to click with my mouse into the first input box (sa-material), and  out from it, in order to the "Add" button will become active.
Would there be any other possible additional code details that would enable the button to be activated and would the code 100% copy the user's operation?
The second inputbox work perfect, there work the type formatting and there is nothing barrier to run the "Add" button method... Thank You!

Comment: Could ways to do it. Easiest is using setTimeout to add a delay for next part runs.

Comment: in those cases it helps dispatching the click event on the element before setting its value and eventually dispatch the blur event. `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))` where `click` is the name of the event. Repeat the same for `blur`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can help to others, who is fighting with this problems, it was the perfect method (the essential thing: bubbles for every events! :-)

```
arrr = document.getElementById('autocomplete-sa-material');
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown', {bubbles: true}));
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseup', {bubbles: true}));
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {bubbles: true}));
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus', {bubbles: true}));
arrr.value = "A-10035951";
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
arrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur', {bubbles: true}));

brrr = document.getElementById('input-sa-quantity');

brrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
brrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
brrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
brrr.value = '23423';
brrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));

crrr = document.getElementById('btn-sa-button-ADDitems');
crrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
crrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
crrr.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

The material inputbox events, when theys bubbling, they enabling the button. And if the button mousedown event is bubbling, it clear the inputbox history values and reset all values, properties...

Thank you all, who had answer earlier, they help to found the answers!